# Question about polynomial rings.

Tags: ring-theory

If $F[x]$ is a polynomial ring, and $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ and $r(x)$ are four polynomials in it, then is it always true that $f(x)=h(x)g(x)+r(x)$ where $deg(r(x))<deg(g(x))$, or is this true only when $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain?

Please note that this question has been edited heavily to make it more coherent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by a field of polynomials? Usually the notation $F[x]$ means the rings of polynomials over $F$, and this is not a field.

Comment: But when $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. What is your question?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- $F[x]$ refers to the field which contains all the elements of $F$, and $x$. It is not merely the ring of polynomials.

Comment: @P..- could you point me to a proof of the same? Thanks

Comment: @AyushKhaitan the standard notation for the field you're referring to is $F(x)$.

Comment: Also, F(x) is not a field of polynomials, but the field of rational functions in $x$ over $F$. How are you defining the degree of such a rational function? In general, a field is a Euclidean domain because every element has degree $0$.

Comment: @ferson2020- you're right! The textbook I'm referring to says the same. Apologies. I'll make the edits.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan OK, but again, how are you defining the degree of an arbitrary element of $F(x)$? What you're asking is trivially true because $f(x) = h(x)g(x)$ where $h(x) = f(x)/g(x)$.

Comment: @ferson2020- I've made some edits to the main question in order to make it more coherent. I'm trying to understand a slightly more general problem, but this might give me direction.

Comment: Given the polynomials, it is not always true. Do you mean to ask, given $f$ and $h$ whether there exists $g$ and $r$ with the prescribed properties? Is $F$ a field?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question gets the logic backwards.  I'll assume that you mean for $F$ to be a field and for $F[x]$ to be the ring of polynomials over that field.  That $F$ is a field guarantees that we can perform [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division_of_polynomials#Euclidean_division) of elements of $F[x]$ using, for example, [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).  That, in turn, implies that $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain.

So in $F[x],$ where $F$ is any field, it is the case that given polynomials $a$ and $b\ne0,$ one can find unique polynomials $q$ and $r$ such that $a=bq+r$ and either $r=0$ or $\deg(r)<\deg(b)$.  This property makes $F[x]$ a Euclidean domain.  These statements are proved in just about any algebra textbook.  See, for example, Section 3.9 in Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*.

Answer (score 0):

If F is an Euclidean domain one can always write f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x), with r(x)=0 or deg(r(x)) less than deg(g(x)); for it you can read papers about Gröbner basis over Euclidean rings, or simply read the division algorithm in the paper of Franz Pauer name's "Gröbner bases with coefficients in rings".